# Observe progress of UIView.animateWithDuration/CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

Is there a way to observe the "time progress" of UIView.animateWithDuration...family of methods from UIView /alternatively CA animations?

I am animating a view's frame and I need to be informed how it is progressing. 
My line of thinking was I can either

1) tap into CAAnimation related stuff or

2) observe the animated properties (like frame) and do my own calculations each screen frame.

Approach 1) turns out to be a dead end, inspecting the internal of how CAAnimations work told me absolutely nothing...and 2) is flawed as the "model layer tree is updated immediately and tapping into the presentation tree is difficult as the presentation layer is nil when you start.

I am pretty desperate, I was thinking that hooking into CADisplayLink will give me a tick and then I simply check something that is affected by the animation but there is nothing to tap to.
Do you think going the NSTimer way that is launched in the same scope as the animation method is ok? If I know animation duration then I can generate the progress myself.

Comment: The `CADisplayLink` approach is a good one. Just examine the `presentationLayer` of the layer being animated. While the layer is updated to its final position, the `presentationLayer` contains the layer properties mid-flight.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22727484/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659736/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15367737/1271826. Or just search for "`presentationLayer` `CADisplayLink`".

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the time value, then you can do math on the `CACurrentMediaTime()` minus the animation start time. I have a sample project on Github called [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) that does exactly that.

That project supports pausing and resuming and scrubbing both `UIView` and `CAAnimation` based animations. In both cases it digs into the underlying `CAAnimations`.

I have another project that uses the values of the animated layer's presentationLayer in order to do hit testing so you can tap on an in-flight view and start/pause the animation. That one can be found here: 
[**iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)

My code uses an `NSTimer` to update the progress of the animation. It would be better to use a `CADisplayLink` timer, as you mentioned.

I am also looking at the new `UIViewPropertyAnimator` class that was added to iOS 10. That makes pausing, reversing, and scrubbing UIView animations easy without having to dig into the underlying `CAAnimations`. See this thread I just posted:

**[Is there a way to observe changes to fractionComplete in UIViewPropertyAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052439/is-there-a-way-to-observe-changes-to-fractioncomplete-in-uiviewpropertyanimator)**